# problems json request from cordova to yahoo weather

Tags: json, cordova, visual-studio-2015, yahoo-api

I'm making an app with apache cordova and I am using the yahoo weather api , my problem is that it gives me an error , the underlying :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.for…odena%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Also, I asked the secret key for the use of bees , but I do not know where to put them in the url .
Someone who can help me ? I am a neophyte , thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're doing this now because you didn't post any type of code, but i would recommend you to use [jQuery simpleWeather](http://simpleweatherjs.com/) for that.

After implementing it you can use this code to make a request to yahoos weather API:

```
    $.simpleWeather({
        woeid: 'YOURWOEID HERE',
        unit: 'c',
        success: function(weather) {
            var sBasicTemp = weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp;
            var sBasicIcon = weather.thumbnail;
            var weatherForecastAll = '<ul class="weatherList">';
            var listClass = '';
            for(var i=0;i<weather.forecast.length;i++) {
                if(i == (weather.forecast.length-1)){listClass = ' class="last"';}
                if(i == 0) {
                    weatherForecastDay = 'Today';
                } else {
                    var forcastDay = weather.forecast[i].day;
                    switch(forcastDay){
                        case('Mon'):
                            weatherForecastDay = 'Monday';
                            break;
                        case('Tue'):
                            weatherForecastDay = 'Tuesday';
                            break;
                        case('Wed'):
                            weatherForecastDay = 'Wednesday';
                            break;
                        case('Thu'):
                            weatherForecastDay = 'Thursday';
                            break;
                        case('Fri'):
                            weatherForecastDay = 'Friday';
                            break;
                        case('Sat'):
                            weatherForecastDay = 'Saturday';
                            break;
                        case('Sun'):
                            weatherForecastDay = 'Sunday';
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        error: function(error) {
            $(".weatherBasicTempHead").html('---');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try use CORS proxy:

```
var link = 'https://linktoapi'; //your link

$.getJSON('http://cors.io/?u=' + link, function(data){ 
    alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar access issue on iOS using Cordova and Yahoo Weather APIs.  It turned out it was a Cordova config access rule needed in the Cordova config.xml:

```
<access origin="http://*"/>
<access origin="https://*"/>
```

Of course these rules are much broader than you want, but it's a simple way to test if this is the cause of your issue.